# Is it legal to use the Tor Network and Tor Software in the United States?

Tags: united-states, internet, open-source-software

Is it legal to use the following provided by the Tor Project:

- Using the Tor Browser
- Using the Tor Network
- Browsing *.onion domains
- Browsing the "Hidden Wiki"

Provided I'm not doing anything illegal with these services/software. I am asking specifically for the United States. Are there any states within the US that prohibit the use of any/all of these services/software?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Tor is not illegal. Nor is hiding your IP address, which is - among other things - what Tor does.

Going to `.onion` links is not illegal. What you find and interact with at those `.onion` sites may be illegal. See Law StackExchange [Is it legal to host a directory of .onion urls?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/is-it-legal-to-host-a-directory-of-onion-urls/7958#7958)

Running a Tor Relay is not illegal. *That could change.* Running an Exit Relay could expose your IP address as the Relay, so that could lead investigators of illegal activity to you. Read https://www.torproject.org/eff/tor-legal-faq.html.en

As always, check your state laws http://statelaws.findlaw.com/criminal-laws/computer-crimes.html

And do your own research with the links above and at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network) and at https://www.torproject.org/