# Can anything be done when people admit to crimes through an online game?

Tags: criminal-law, internet, punishment

When playing an online game recently, I heard two players on voice chat discussing how they've raped women before.

Over the years, I've heard many awful things said through voice chat, but nothing like this. And though it was only discussed briefly, it was quite disturbing. I was actually able to record a bit of their conversation, and think I've narrowed it down to the two players who said it.

Now I'm unsure of what to do about it. Is this something worth taking up with law enforcement, or just Sony (since it happened through the Playstation Network)?

I do apologize if I've worded/tagged this question incorrectly.

Update: No dates, no names, and no places were mentioned in their conversation. All I have is their usernames.

Comment: Even if it is true, it could be sufficient far in the past that the statute of limitations has passed, and without knowing the true names of the users and the names of the victims there is little to report. Read this: http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16225/where-can-i-report-criminal-intent-found-on-the-dark-web

Answer (score 2):

If you have knowledge of a serious crime then you can (and in some jurisdictions, are required) to report it to the police.

**However, you don't have such knowledge**

People say things that aren't true. They do this a lot on the internet. In fact, it was I who shot JFK: I did it 5 years before I was born which is a neat trick but not beyond the abilities of the mafia/Cuban/Russian syndicates I was working for, when they catch me I will tell them how it was done.

Does this internet communication contain any actual facts like names, places and dates? Or is it two anonymous wankers big-noting themselves?

Comment: I do appreciate these responses. To answer your question: no dates, no names, and no places were mentioned. Would that indicate there's nothing I can actually do?

Comment: It raises the question of what are you going to report - that you heard to anonymous people saying things that might or might not be true - sounds like a priority investigation for underfunded police (sarcasm)